# Универстальная процедура PostgresQL

Tags: stored-procedures, postgresql

нужна универсальная процедура для postgresQL, которая на вход получает sql запрос, и на выходе возвращает результат этого запроса.

Такое извращение нужно для одного сервиса.

Пример процедуры:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test(sql varchar)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
return execute (sql);
END; 
$$;
```

Вызов:

```
call test('select * from table')
```

С процедурами слабо знаком. Может кто подсткажет, реализуемо ли такое ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(sql text, _tbl_type anyelement)
RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS
$func$
    BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql;
    END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Usage:

```
select from test('select from venues', NULL::venues)
```